# VB DataGridView Row State

Tags: vb.net

How can I get datagridview rowstate like `Modified, Added, Unchanged` and so on? If I use DataGridView.Rows.State, it will return `Displayed, Visible`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State of the DataGridViewRow is not the same as the row state of the DataTable. If you want that you need to bind DataGridView to DataTable so that data item of each row is DataRow instance, then you can get that DataRow via DataBoundItem property and inspect the RowState of the bound DataRow instance.
ref =  [How to get the row state of Datagridview?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/a5a277d1-0c10-4701-bd43-68d061bc408c/)